# Android Null Pointer Exception in Retrofit response

Tags: android, api, nullpointerexception, callback, retrofit

In my application i have been using retrofit for my webservice calls. It  is working fine but when application goes in to background it crashes and got the error log as,

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void    retrofit.Callback.failure(retrofit.RetrofitError)' on a null object   reference
    at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)


Can anyone help me to overcome this issue..??
```

This is my Retrofit client class,

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static RetrofitCommonService RETROFIT_CLIENT;
public RetrofitClient() {}
public static RetrofitCommonService getInstance() {
    //if REST_CLIENT is null then set-up again.
    if (RETROFIT_CLIENT == null) {
        setupRestClient();
    }
    return RETROFIT_CLIENT;
}

private static void setupRestClient() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
            .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL)
            //.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
    RETROFIT_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(RetrofitCommonService.class);
}
}
```

This is my Retrofit Service interface,

```
 public interface RetrofitCommonService {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/user")
void doRegistration(@Field("user[mobile_number]") String phone, @Field("user[new_uid]") String imei,
                    Callback<RetrofitResponse> response);

 }
```

And this way i am making a call to Retrofit service from my activity and activity implementing retrofit callbacks.

```
 RetrofitCommonService mRetrofitCommonService = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    mRetrofitCommonService.doRegistration(mPhoneNumber, getDeviceId(), this);

public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity implements Callback<RetrofitResponse>{

}

@Override
public void success(RetrofitResponse retrofitResponse, Response response) {

      }

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
}
```

Comment: You provided not much more than the error message. It says that the `Callback` object was `null`. So make sure you do asynchronous calls always with a valid `Callback`.

Comment: put some code here this is too vague

Comment: Ok i will post my code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fixed this issue**.

In my activity i have two Retrofit services operations and these two services relay on same Retrofit Callback methods. And these causes null pointer when one service try to get a callback at the same time callback is used by other service. I have removed the callback methods and used return objects from Retrofit service. Then relaying on the callback method is not needed.

*This worked for me...*

Comment: We have the same problem according to Google Play crash reports. How can we regenerate the case (situation) on development environment. Any suggested steps?

Answer (score 1):

Callback should be properly initialized before calling the method that invokes the callback.